# Application of DCT, integrability on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be integrable on $[0,\infty$).

Show that lim$_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $\int_0^{\infty}$ $f(x) \frac{x}{n+x}$ $dx$ = $0$.

Ok so I want to say I can take the limit inside, but this is a consequence of DCT or MCT, so to apply DCT, this is what I have come up with so far:

define $f_n$ = $f(x)$ $\cdot$ $\frac{x}{n+x}$ (my intuition from previous measure theory problems is that I need this step)

then {$f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions,

but are the $f_n$ bounded above $f(x)$ ?

*Note by assumption we have $\int_0^{\infty}$ $f(x)$ $dx < \infty$.

Using all of this am I able to somehow deduce that

lim$_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $\int_0^{\infty}$ $f(x) \frac{x}{n+x}$ $dx$ =  $\int_0^{\infty}$ $f(x)$ lim$_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $\frac{x}{n+x}$ $dx$ = $\int_0^{\infty}$ $f(x)$ $dx$ $\int_0^{\infty}$ lim$_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $\frac{x}{n+x}$ $dx$

I am VERY hesitant on my above two equalities, specially the last one, where am I wrong or need input? Thanks in advance and sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Are you really asking if $\frac{x}{n+x} \le 1$ for $x > 0$ and $n \ge 1$?

Comment: omg duh, $x > 0$. I didn't consider that, thats why I said forgive me If im asking something obvious, Im learning, I don't learn fast. SORRY FOR BEING STUPID.

Comment: happens to all of us

Comment: lol thanks, again, Im new to measure theory, im really trying to get a lot better so feel free to comment if you ever see me ask noob questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do this from scratch. First, integrability reads $\int |f(x)|<\infty$. Now, set $f_n(x)= f(x)\frac{x}{n+x}$, and observe that, $|f_n(x)|\leq |f(x)|$ point wise, as $\frac{x}{n+x}\leq 1$ holds always, whenever $x\geq 0$, and $n\geq 1$.

Now, also note that, for any fixed $x$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$, point wise. Hence, by DCT, $\lim_n \int f_n(x)\; dx=\int \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\; dx = 0$, as $\lim_n f_n(x)=0$.